# Choosing a function from a list and applying it to generate an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

OK, I didn't know how to explain it in the title, but here is what I am trying to do (Python):

I have a list of initialized functions, say `[foo, bar]`, and for every input, I have an associated index of which function to use. Now given an array of inputs `X`, index array `I`, I need to generate output array `y` assuming the conditions above.

My solution:

```
## These are just example methods, in reality there are complex functions
def foo(x):
    return x
def bar(x):
    return x - 1

f = [foo, bar]
X = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 8, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1]
I = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

solution_functions = numpy.take(f, I)
solution_result = [solution_functions[idx](X[idx]) for idx in I]
```

My question is there a more efficient way of doing that -- the problem is that if `X` has thousands of elements, and functions in `f` are really complex, I will have create too many objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly simplify the logic by changing to the following:

```
>>> [f[i](x) for x, i in zip(X, I)]
[1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 0]
```

Note that if the length of `X` and `I` are different, it will truncate to the shortest length.

The `zip` function returns an iterator, which will likely make this more memory-efficient. If you expect the same expensive function to be run on the same values multiple times, you can also implement caching, for instance by decorating the functions with [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

If you plan to loop through these values and don't need them all at the same time, you can make this a generator expression by placing it in parentheses instead of brackets: this will only calculate each value as you need it.